# JS function is breaking remaining functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a function which breaks ALL other javascript / jquery on the page.

What I'm trying to do with the function below is duplicate a div upon button press and append it after the initial one (can be duplicated as many times as pressed) - and it works great, except everything else breaks.

I've added the snippets above it just for reference, but it's the actual function `duplicateContact()` which is causing the issues.

If someone could help with pointing out my mistake I'd love to be able to use the function without having it kill everything else.

```
//add more contacts
document.getElementById('C_addContact').onclick = duplicateContact;


var i = 0;
var original = document.getElementById('C_contacts');
var nextElement = $.extend(original);

function duplicateContact()
{
    var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
    clone.id = "C_contacts" + ++i; // there can only be one element with an ID

    nextElement.parentNode.insertBefore(clone, nextElement.nextSibling);

}
```

Below is my remaining js:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//show hidden div upon select box selection
$(function() {
    $('#otherTitleField').hide(); 
    $('#title').change(function(){
        if($('#title').val() == 'Other') {
            $('#otherTitleField').show(); 
        } else {
            $('#otherTitleField').hide(); 
        } 
    });
});


//show hidden div upon radio button selection
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
       if($(this).attr('id') == 'postno') {
            $('#postalnofield').show(); 
       }        
       else {
            $('#postalnofield').hide();   
       }
   });
});

//show different hidden div based on checkboxes
function valueChanged1()
{
    if($('#tfn').is(":checked")) {
        $("#tfnfield").show();
    }
    else
        $("#tfnfield").hide();
}

function valueChanged2()
{
    if($('#abn').is(":checked")) {
        $("#abnfield").show();
    }
    else
        $("#abnfield").hide();
}

//clear contacts div
function clearBox(elementID)
{
    if(elementID != 'C_contacts') {
        document.getElementById(elementID).innerHTML = "";
    }

}
</script>
```

And the HTML for the div which is being cloned:

```
<div id="C_contacts">
    <p><label for="C_familyName">Family name<span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" id="C_familyName" name="Section C Family Name" required></p>

    <p><span style="display:inline-block; width:49%;">
    <label for="C_givenName">First given name<span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" id="C_givenName" name="Section C Given Name" required></span>

    <span style="display:inline-block; width:49%;">
    <label for="C_otherName">Other given name/s<span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" id="C_otherName" name="Section C Other Names" required>
    </span></p>

    <p><label for="C_position">Position held<span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" id="C_position" name="Section C Position Held" required></p>

    <p><span style="display:inline-block; width:49%;">
    <label for="C_busPhone">Business phone<span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
    <input type="tel" id="C_busPhone" name="Section C Business Phone" required>
    </span>

    <span style="display:inline-block; width:49%;">
    <label for="C_mobPhone">Mobile phone</label>
    <input type="tel" id="C_mobPhone" name="Section C Mobile">
    </span></p>

    <p><label for="C_busEmail">Business email address</label>
    <input type="email" id="C_busEmail" name="Section C Email"></p>

    <p><label for="C_thisApp C_busOp">This person is the authorised contact for information about:<span class="mandatory">*</span></label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="C_thisApp" name="This Application" value="thisApp"> this application<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="C_busOp" name="Operation of Business" value="busOp"> the operation of the business after we have granted a licence</p>

    <p><input type="button" id="C_removeContact" value="Remove contact" onclick="clearBox(this.parentNode.parentNode.id)"></p>
    <p><input type="button" id="C_addContact" onclick="duplicateContact()" value="Add more contacts"></p>

    <hr>
    </div>
```

**UPDATE:** Apparently I had two versions of jquery which was causing issues. I have no idea how I missed this - thank you to everyone for the suggestions and help, this is resolved.

Comment: can you share the html also

Comment: whether elements like `otherTitleField` are within the cloned element

Comment: Is there any errors shown in console.

Comment: What's broken about it?

Comment: At least I think you're assigning the same I'd for two elements there since you change also nextElement's ID

Comment: @Ibu No other javascript works on the page (it's as if it's not there). If I remove the duplicateContact function it all works again.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I'm using nextElement to append the newly cloned div to the after the last cloned div. Is there a better way to do this? I was stuck with this for a while as it kept appending to the original div, not the clones.

Comment: You can append, but why are you changing the ID of it also? That won't make it point to the last added div

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Right - I'm not sure ahha. I've never really used Javascript and I had just adapted a code snipped I found online to try and suit my needs. You're right, it's not neccessary - I've removed it and it still appends to the last added div - but my original concern is still present.. No other JS works while this function is present :(

Comment: @RohanKumar yes - There is an error present when the function in question is also present: "TypeError: 'contains' called on an object that does not implement interface Node."; however, I am unsure what it means.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is your actual code, but I can see every time you are cloning a div in which you are cloning `remove and add buttons`. But you need to create a single `Add button` for cloning and there are remove buttons for all clone divs. Also your function `clearBox` is not called for the newly generated divs, to make it work you can use [jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) and use [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle) to show hide so that your code can be short. Below is the working snippet which can help you for your functionality

```js
//add more contacts
document.getElementById('C_addContact').onclick = duplicateContact;
var i = 0;
var original = document.getElementById('C_contacts');
var nextElement = $.extend(original);

function duplicateContact() {
  var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
  clone.id = "C_contacts" + ++i; // there can only be one element with an ID
  nextElement.parentNode.insertBefore(clone, nextElement.nextSibling);
}

//show hidden div upon select box selection
$(function() {
  $('#otherTitleField').hide();
  $('#title').change(function() {
    $('#otherTitleField').toggle(this.value == 'Other');
  });
  //show hidden div upon radio button selection
  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
    $('#postalnofield').toggle(this.id == 'postno');
  });
  // using event delegation with document for removing dynamic divs
  $(document).on('click', '.remove-contacts', function() {
    $(this).closest('.c-contacts').attr('id') !== 'C_contacts' &&
      $(this).closest('.c-contacts').remove();
  });
});
//show different hidden div based on checkboxes
function valueChanged1() {
  $("#tfnfield").toggle($('#tfn').is(":checked"));
}

function valueChanged2() {
  $("#abnfield").toggle($('#abn').is(":checked"));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="C_contacts" class="c-contacts">
  <p>
    <label for="C_familyName">Family name<span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" id="C_familyName" name="Section C Family Name" required>
  </p>

  <p><span style="display:inline-block; width:49%;">
    <label for="C_givenName">First given name<span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" id="C_givenName" name="Section C Given Name" required>
    </span>

    <span style="display:inline-block; width:49%;">
    <label for="C_otherName">Other given name/s<span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" id="C_otherName" name="Section C Other Names" required>
    </span>
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="C_position">Position held<span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" id="C_position" name="Section C Position Held" required>
  </p>

  <p><span style="display:inline-block; width:49%;">
    <label for="C_busPhone">Business phone<span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
    <input type="tel" id="C_busPhone" name="Section C Business Phone" required>
    </span>

    <span style="display:inline-block; width:49%;">
    <label for="C_mobPhone">Mobile phone</label>
    <input type="tel" id="C_mobPhone" name="Section C Mobile">
    </span></p>

  <p>
    <label for="C_busEmail">Business email address</label>
    <input type="email" id="C_busEmail" name="Section C Email">
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="C_thisApp C_busOp">This person is the authorised contact for information about:<span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="C_thisApp" name="This Application" value="thisApp"> this application
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="C_busOp" name="Operation of Business" value="busOp"> the operation of the business after we have granted a licence</p>

  <p>
    <input type="button" id="C_removeContact" value="Remove contact" class="remove-contacts">
  </p>
  <hr>
</div>
<p>
  <input type="button" id="C_addContact" value="Add more contacts">
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for this - yes, I know I was duplicating the 'add more contacts' button, but was having trouble getting a single button to work :( Your working snippet has helped with that!